# Sort on matching number of days in period with Solr

Tags: solr, spatial, solr4, date-range

We are asked to implement a new feature in one of our sites and after a certain amount of research we think that we can't solve this within Solr. But we briefly want to double check this;

Let's say we store Companies in our index. Every company can have multiple opening periods. A period is formatted as "start day (date)" to "end day (date)". At the website we allow our visitor to search on a period and we show them the companies which match at least one day of the company's periods. So far so good, we already implemented this with Spatial Search;
(https://people.apache.org/~hossman/spatial-for-non-spatial-meetup-20130117/).

Our field(type) definition:

```
<fieldType name="dayrange" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" geo="false" worldBounds="ENVELOPE(16071, 20088, 20088, 16071)" distErrPct="0" maxDistErr="1" units="degrees"/>

<field name="periods" type="dayrange" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false"/>
```

*Note: the worldBounds are based on the days since epoch. Start day is 1 jan 2014 (16071 days since epoch) and the end day is 31 dec 2024 (20088 days since epoch).*

Whenever we want to search we use the contains method: `fq=periods:"INTERSECTS(16071 16733 16739 20088)"`

Like i said, so far so good. This is already working. Now they asked us to implement two new features;

1. Allow sorting based on the number of matching days
2. Display the number of matching days (This company is opened on 10 of the 14 days you searched for)

The second feature *could* also be implemented outside Solr (e.g. in our application). But if its possible to sort on the number of matching days, it will probably also be possible to return that number?! For performance reasons we prefer to implement the sorting thing on Solr. But right now we couldn't find a good solution to implement this. 
Anyone who can help us with the right solution or can confirm this is not possible with native Solr 4.x?!

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little bit tricky since you has a several intervals per company.

In case of one interval you can use "sort by function" option. 
For this you should add two fields to your Sorl schema
start date in days and end date in days to you schena and made sort by function `sub(max(start,start_q),mine(and,end_q)) desc`.[Funcation Query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery)

In case of several intervals Solr will not know which values of start and of end should be taken. To support several interval you will be need a writing a custom java lib  for Solr to support this. I have created prototype for such lib [lucene-custom-score](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/lucene-custom-score).

First you will need to store a start and end of interval in one field with [docValues="true"](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DocValues).  It is good idea to use long type for this field and code values as end*20088+start. [Here](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/lucene-custom-score/blob/master/src/main/java/com/akuznetsov/ExampleOfPeriodSum.java#L32) you can find an example of lucene document creations. Here field is called a “intervals”.

Next you should write a query with custom scoring. You can find example of such one [PeriodSumQuery](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/lucene-custom-score/blob/master/src/main/java/com/akuznetsov/PeriodSumQuery.java). The score is calculated in method [PeriodSumScoreProvider#periodSum](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/lucene-custom-score/blob/master/src/main/java/com/akuznetsov/PeriodSumQuery.java#L265).

In this method intervals are retrieved from docvalues and weight is calculated.

To enable this score in Solr you need to defile a custom [query parser plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#QParserPlugin.) in sorlschema.xml. The example of custom such plugin in [PeriodSumQueryParser](https://github.com/AKuznetsov/lucene-custom-score/blob/master/src/main/java/com/akuznetsov/PeriodSumQueryParser.java). For simplicity start and end of search interval are passed as additional parameter in search url. But with some effort, they can be retrieved from query string.